# hive issue when activating yarn FairScheduler

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, scheduler, beeline, hiveserver2

After activating yarn FairScheduler, i am note able to run beeline hive,
i have this error on hiveserver2 :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.AllocationFileLoaderService: method ()V not found
and this error on beeline : ERROR jdbc.HiveConnection: Error opening session
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
command:
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://192.168.0.1:10000/default"

After activating yarn FairScheduler, i am note able to run beeline hive,
normally when i run command:
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://192.168.0.1:10000/default"
i will be able to run query